# Replace values in PySpark column directly without joining

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames:

```py
data1 = [('Andy', 'male'), ('Julie', 'female'), ('Danny', 'male')]
columns1 = ['name', 'gender']
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns1)


data2 = [('male', 1), ('female', 2)]
columns2 = ['gender', 'enum']
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=columns2)
```

```
+-----+------+                                                                  
| name|gender|
+-----+------+
| Andy|  male|
|Julie|female|
|Danny|  male|
+-----+------+

+------+----+
|gender|enum|
+------+----+
|  male|   1|
|female|   2|
+------+----+
```

I am looking to replace column `gender` in `df1` with the `enum` values from `df2`. I could do this by:

```py
new_df = df1.join(df2, on='gender', how='inner')
```

And then drop column `gender`, and rename column `enum` in `new_df` to `gender`. This is cumbersome and depends on column `gender` to be of the same name in both `df1` and `df2`.

Is there a way to directly replace the values without these intermediate steps?

Comment: If you have limited genders to replace then you can try using when otherwise to replace the column values in single step

Comment: In my real data frame, column ```gender``` has many more categorial values (and hence, as many corresponding ```enum``` values.

Comment: Then using [df.na.replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html) with dictionary of values and gender column as subset in df1 might work

Comment: Can you define "many more"? Because if that's one thousands, you can still collect the data onto the driver and write a UDF.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you explain why you don't want to do this with a join ?
Are you trying to optimize performance or readability ? If it's because of performance, fear not, as Spark will automatically perform a [Broadcast Join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html#join-hints-types). If it's for readability, I guess you can always encapsulate the logic in a generic function and call it directly. Also, df.na.replace is a good option too. UDFs work as well but they are slower in Python, I would recommend them for Java and Scala only.

Comment: @Oli That's correct, the category list would rise to the order of thousands.

Comment: @FurryMachine It's not that I don't want to use join, I am just wondering if there is better way. My task is to keep track of a list of categories and update and enum it regularly, and update any data frame that contain a column of these categories. Just wondering there is simpler and neat way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without join you would need to provide all the possible mappings yourself

```py
df = df.replace({'male':'1', 'female':'2'}, subset='gender')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `df2` does not contain more than a few thousand elements, you can collect all the data and write a udf like this:

```py
df2_list = df2.collect()
d = sc.broadcast(dict([(c[0], c[1]) for c in df2_list]))
replace = f.udf(lambda x: d.value[x])

# then you can use replace on any dataframe like this;
df1.withColumn("gender", replace("gender")).show()
+-----+------+
| name|gender|
+-----+------+
| Andy|     1|
|Julie|     2|
|Danny|     1|
+-----+------+
```

I am not sure it is simpler, but it is another way at it.

NB: the broad cast is not mandatory, but it will allow the dictionary to be sent to each executor only once instead of every single task.